# Función de importación personalizada para django-import-export

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, csv

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
def import_matches_from_csv():
    # TODO: Change the encode characters
    with open('/code/matches.csv', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in spamreader:
            print(row)
            if row[0] != 'Fecha':
                match = Match()
                match.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d-%b-%y").date()
                match.cup = Edition.objects.get(edition=row[1])
                team_1 = slugify(row[2])
                match.team_1 = Country.objects.get(slug=team_1)
                match.goals_1 = row[3]
                match.score = row[4]
                match.goals_2 = row[5]
                team_2 = slugify(row[6])
                match.team_2 = Country.objects.get(slug=team_2)
                match.fixture = row[7]
                match.gep = parse_gep(row[8])
                winner = slugify(row[9])
                match.winner = Country.objects.get(slug=winner)
                match.save()
```

La uso para cargar un archivo *CSV* con la siguiente estructura:

```
date,cup,team_1,goals_1,score,goals_2,team_2,fixture,gep,winner
3-Jun-16,45,EE.UU.,0,0 - 4,4,Colombia,EE.UU. vs Colombia,DerrotaE1,Colombia
```

Intento importar este archivo con `django-impor-export`pero tengo muchos problemas con este paquete:

- El *CSV* no tiene campo `id` porque con estos datos voy a crear objetos nuevos. Obviamente los `id` se generarían automáticamente.
- El *CSV* no tiene `id` para llaves foráneas, yo obtengo la llave foránea convirtiendo en `slug` el contenido de ciertos campos y buscando con ese `slug` los objetos cuyo `slug`sea el mismo.
- Tengo que analizar la fecha debido a que el formato de la fecha es diferente al de *Django*.

[image: __gol_y_futbol]

Este es el problema que tengo.

He intentado hacer algunos arreglos con el siguiente código, pero no funciona:

```
class MatchResource(resources.ModelResource):
    date = fields.Field(column_name='date', attribute='date', widget=DateWidget(format="%d-%b-%y"))
    cup = fields.Field(
        column_name='cup',
        attribute='cup',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Edition, 'edition'))

class Meta:
    model = Match
    widgets = {
        'date': {'format': '%d-%b-%y'},
    }
```

¿Qué es lo que está mal en ese código y cuál podría ser su solución?

Comment: Creo que son varios problemas en uno solo. Por un lado, está el problema del `id` que tienes que generar, el `slug` que tienes que buscar, luego el problema de la fechas que tienes que convertir. Te intentes solucionar estos problemas por separado, y si lo necesitas, hagas las preguntas relacionadas con ese problema concreto. En este momento, la pregunta, con tres problemas, es demasiado amplia.

Answer (score 0):

Dale un formato a fecha, por ejemplo.
 `fecha= datetime.datetime.now(
                        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`